# How trim spaces from field in MongoDB query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I would like rebuild autocomplete to work on MongoDB.

I show an example in PostgreSQL

```
@parts = Part.where("replace(parts.code,' ','') ilike '%?%'",
                     params[:q].gsub(' ','')
                   )
             .limit(10)
```

How to run that by MongoID. I must clear white spaces because users send it by different ways (eg. Bosch has number 0 986 039 260, so 0986039260 should return the same part)

Please hint how to do it.

Comment: This part `replace(parts.code,' ','')` made your job _tough_. Why didn't you put the data by stripping while putting it into DB.. can you update the column values by striping all leading/trailing white spaces ? If you can do then there is a chance to write it using `Part.where(code.regex =>params[:q].gsub(' ','')).limit(10)`..

Comment: Or try `Part.where("this.code.replace(" ","") == ?", params[:q].gsub(' ','')).limit(10)`

Comment: I can't strip it in DB because I must have oryginal part index. Results of your secound answer: `@selector={:count=>"mongo_indices", :query=>{"$where"=>"this.code.replace(,) == 'LAU 11.0890'"}}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 16722: "exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,"`

Comment: Well.._syntax error_.. Humm... `result = params[:q].gsub(' ',''); Part.where("this.code.replace(/\s+/,'') == #{result}").limit(10)` <~~ Try this

Comment: `Part.where("this.code.replace(' ','') == '#{result}'").limit(10)` It's works Thanks Arup !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer, I have made for you :

```
result = params[:q].gsub(' ','')
Part.where("this.code.replace(/\s+/,'') == #{result}")
    .limit(10)
```

Took the idea from [this link](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#limit).